# Regarding a plural or singular problem

Tags: plural-forms

Let me thank you in advance.

I am taking ( for my just blog purpose ) a listening test, which is,
the gate examination to enter his/her university for entire students
in our country. And I struck upon a very annoying problem? which is,
whether speaker should end with either plural or singular. Kindly take 
a look at below.

( The listening test answer )

> Woman : How many emails do you usually get a day?
>
> Man : Around 90
>
> Woman : That many?
>
> Man : Yeah, but **a third of them are junk mail.**

Now I am wondering if the bold part is correct or not. I think "a third of them" 
takes singular, so that "are" should not be used as you can see the man ends up
with singular. Personally, I think this is a mistake. Am I correct or not?

Thank you for your kind assistance in advance.

Comment: Ask yourself this: If a third of 90 emails are junk, then he gets 60 bona-fide ones. Since 60 is more than 1, don't you think that a plural verb would seem appropriate?

Comment: It could, but it is not necessary since 'mail' is used generically (as a non-count noun). The subject is "a third of them" where "them" is interpreted anaphorically as "90 emails". "The fraction "a third" is the head of the NP "A third of them", but it is the complement of the preposition "of" (i.e. "them") that determines the verb-form. Since "them" is plural, the verb must also be plural.

Comment: Look here: [link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mail)

Comment: I agree with BillJ: I occasionally hear people say "mails" or "emails" to refer to "individual pieces of mail" but that is non-standard and sounds ugly.

Comment: @stangdon *emails* is used a heck of a lot and is not ugly to many people. [have a look](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=Emails)

Comment: @Clare - You do realize most of those uses are by people who don't speak English as their first language, right?  I'm not saying people *never* use "emails", but it's as ugly as using "mails" to refer to multiple pieces of postal mail.

Comment: @BillJ Could you write an answer?